# Structuring data in firestore and referencing users

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a React/Firebase app, and I need to structure my data so that many users can use the app with proper performance and security.

Here's the outline:

I've got the standard firebase users (for authentication), and an extra `users` collection to store extra data about each user (address, etc).

Every user should have has a bunch of tasks, only accessible/viewable by the user himself. Tasks cannot be shared between users.

Besides tasks, there can be many other types of documents that are user-specific. For instance, projects. Different projects can contain the same tasks, but the projects are user-specific.

Should I store all tasks in a `tasks` collection, all projects in a `projects` collection, then referencing which user the task/projects belongs to in every task/project document? In such case, do I simply store the uid of each user in the document?

Or should I have a collection `tasks`, a collection `projects`, with a sub-collection for each user?

The main concerns are performance and security, I have no idea how firestore compares to classic relational databases as far as performance goes.

Comment: This will all depend on your requirements, but you might want to do a tasks subcollection for each user. For example: Are tasks shared between users? Whenever I create a database structure it sometimes helps me to fully describe the purposes and connections between every collection/documents/etc in plain english and that usually gets me most of the way to figuring out how I want to store everything.

Comment: Clarified the question.

Comment: If you are new to noSQL databases and Firestore, i highly recommend the Get to Know Cloud Firestore video series on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ This playlist helped me a lot to get started with firestore. For an overview on how to structure your database i recommend video number 5. And your security concerns are addressed in video number 6.